# What is the proper way of dealing with situations where you need to save a file and keep a reference to it?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and have learned it on-the-job (as opposed to first learning the technically correct ways of solving related problems).

One problem I encounter often is situations where I need to both (1) save a file to the server and (2) save a reference to the file, e.g. the file name in the datase. Because (1) or (2) can fail, I set up my procedure like

```
Try (1)
If (1) fails, exit procedure; else, try (2)
If (2) fails, undo (1)
```

Here are my questions about this:

- What if `undo` (1) fails? Then what should I do?
- Should I do the steps in the opposite order (First do the db submission and then rollback transaction if can't save corresponding file)?
- Is there some resource you can guide me to for how to approach problems like this?

Comment: What are you using for SQL? Can you use a FILESTREAM data type in your data table? If you can that can give you transactional file access.

Comment: Your question is quite broad, and has less to do with any particular technology and more to do with error handling in general.  There is no "one size fits all" solution here.  The approach you use and the options at your disposal will depend on the operations your performing, the sequence of those operations, and the systems those operations rely on.

Comment: As @MichaelPetito, your question is too broad. You may specify what are the data stores you are using. You could use [.NET Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx) if the data are being saved on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.Net transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). It will allow you to roll everything back if they both don't succeed.